# detecting plugins on IE11 using javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have a web app that requires a number of plugins/add-on and I need to detect whether the user has those add-ons or not, if it was IE10 or earlier I have no problem I can use a VBscript. I've tried the

```
 navigator.plugin
```

object which returns an empty array. I know the programs are supported in IE11 I just have no way of detecting them since VBscript is depricated.

Comment: Use feature detection, not add-on detection. What exactly are you checking for?

Comment: Do you have any sites or examples you and point me too, everything I have looked up points me to detecting IE11, when I already can do that. An example detecting if they have java web start

Comment: @JakobHartman One approach is to try and use the feature, listening for any exceptions to be thrown. If the browser is unable to perform your request, you know whether or not the feature is supported.

Comment: Would something like http://modernizr.com/ help?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Modernizr is meant for detecting standards support. It wouldn't work for this particular example. Of course, you *could* extend Modernizr to cover these cases, if that was appropriate for your team and project.

Comment: Have you see the Cross-browser plugin detection article on MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn423948(v=vs.85).aspx)?  It describes some of the techniques you're looking for.  (Kind of surprised that @JonathanSampson didn't mention it.  :-P)

Comment: @LanceLeonard I get the feeling you know more about MSDN content than I do :)

Comment: You're kind, @JonathanSampson.  Even if ever fully true, I'm sure it's a temporary condition, especially as the relevance fades.

Comment: Johnathan can you post an answer so I can check you on being right